# Jolt transform an object with an array to a single array

Tags: java, json, jolt

Hello everyone my json input is this:

```
{
  "chequesCollateral": [
    {
      "accountNum": "0026.0002.62.0300162968",
      "agreement": "0026.5501.90.0490520505",
      "checkno": "229425941           ",
      "amount": 20000,
      "issueBank": "0026",
      "branch": "0154",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "expDate": "2019-09-20"
    },
    {
      "accountNum": "0026.0002.62.0300162968",
      "agreement": "0026.5501.90.0490520505",
      "checkno": "322108888           ",
      "amount": 2500,
      "issueBank": "0011",
      "branch": "0335",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "expDate": "2019-10-26"
    },
    {
      "accountNum": "0026.0002.62.0300162968",
      "agreement": "0026.5501.90.0490520505",
      "checkno": "321979826           ",
      "amount": 3964.77,
      "issueBank": "0011",
      "branch": "0104",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "expDate": "2019-10-31"
    }
  ]
}
```

I use this transform to produce this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "chequesCollateral": {
        "*": {
          "issueBank": "distinctBinData.&0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and this is produced:

```
{
  "distinctBinData" : {
    "issueBank" : [ "0026", "0011", "0011" ]
  }
}
```

I want to produce this :

```
{
  "distinctBinData" : [ "0026", "0011", "0011" ]
}
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the `&0` part in the destination key. `&0` refers to the current level JSON key, which is `issueBank` in your case. So when you specified the destination key as `distinctBinData.&0`, it resolves to `distinctBinData.issueBank`. So just use `distinctBinData` as the destination key as follows.

```
[
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "chequesCollateral": {
            "*": {
                "issueBank": "distinctBinData"
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```